# Move Slick Slider gallery when mouse is on left or right side of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to get my gallery to move left when the mouse is on the left side of the page and move right when it is on the right side of the page. 
Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/protonus/16py51pm/3/). I tried to use the hover function but it doesn't work. Mouseover seems to only work when you move the mouse over either on left or right side of the page and mousemove only seems to work when you move the mouse again. I would like it to still move (left or right) when the mouse is stationary (in either left or right side of page), or moved.

```js
$('.carousel-one').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  "use strict";
  var mouseSide;
  if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2) {
    $('.carousel-one').slickPrev();
  } else {
    $('.carousel-one').slickNext();
  }
});
$('.carousel-one').slick({
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-one">
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `pauseOnHover: false,`. Hope this helps!

```js
$('.carousel-one').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  "use strict";
  var mouseSide;
  if ((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) < $(this).width() / 2) {
    $('.carousel-one').slickPrev(); 
  } else {
    $('.carousel-one').slickNext();
  }
});
$('.carousel-one').slick({
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  pauseOnHover: false, 
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-one">
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image three"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image one"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image two"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/200" alt="Image four"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Image five"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="Image seven"></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" alt="Image six"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shridar it is still doing the same thing. I want the gallery to move left when the mouse is on the left side, even when the mouse is stationary. The same with the right side. I hope this elaborates more.

Comment: You wanted slides to move even when the mouse is stationary. So even if you mouseOver, the slides still move. You wanted the slides to keep moving isn't it?

Comment: Correct, so when the user either moves the mouse to left side or leaves the mouse on the left side then the gallery should move left. The same for the right side.

Comment: The movement is continous if run code snippet in stackoverflow itself, but it doesn't work in jsfiddle.

Comment: Possibly this is a bug. You should put this issue on github.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if I leave the mouse there, the gallery moves in the wrong direction, I know that is from the autoplay variable. But is it possible to move the gallery when the mouse is stationary on a specific side? So if I remove the autoplay variable and the mouse is one either the left or right side it should still move.